# Special linear group of degree $d$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $p$ is odd prime. For each $1\leqslant d\leqslant p-1.$ Let $SL^d_n(\mathbb{F}_p) = \{X\in GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)\,\,:\,\,(det X)^d = 1\}$ be the special linear group of degree $d$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p.$

Show that $SL^{p-1}_n(\mathbb{F}_p) = GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)?$ Here's what I have:

Proof. We have homomorphism $\det: GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)\to \mathbb{F}_p^* = \mathbb{F}_p\setminus\{0\}$ is an epimorphism.

For all $X\in GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p),$ then $\det X\in \mathbb{F}_p^*,$ so $(\det X, p) = 1.$

Hence, from Fermat's little theorem, one gets $(det X)^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p.$

Therefore, $ SL^{p-1}_n(\mathbb{F}_p) = GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p).$

Is it right or wrong?

Comment: This is a trivial consequence of the fact that the multiplicative group of $\mathbb F_p$ has order $p-1$.

Comment: Please tell me how to prove this statement!

Comment: The determinant is an element of the field $\mathbb{F}_p$, the multiplicative group of which has order $p-1$.

Comment: I don't see what the question is. You have a proof (more or less) already in the answer (or Mariano's comment, which has the advantage of working even if $p$ is not prime).

Comment: tomasz p is odd prime

Comment: I think this question has some irrelevant tags...